# URL problem with ASP to ASP.NET again

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting, seo, url-routing

I will explain again with sample codes.. We have an ASP site. It has too much contents you can look to this ASP site [here for sample link1](http://www.etkinpatent.com/haberlericerik-11-121-marka-tescilininde-yasanan-sorunlar.html). Now we have to change this site to ASP.NET you can look this ASP.NET sample page [here for sample link2](http://www.kalite.biz.tr/marka-tescilininde-yasanan-sorunlar.html). Our domain will not change. But our old urls will change, you can see link1 and link2 differences...The problem is google robot indexed our old urls and robot will come again but will not find our old urls so it will give us bad points... How can we solve this problem??

I will give sample codes for asp.net seo...maybe It can help to you for this problem..

Global.asax:

```
string path= System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.FilePath).ToLower();

else if (f.GlobalasaxLink("select ID,url from Tbl_Contents", path, "url", "content") != "")
        {
            Context.RewritePath(f.GlobalasaxLink("select ID,url from Tbl_Contents", path, "url", "content"), false);
        }
```

in ASP.NET we are saving to db all content's url..

Class F and Function GlobalasaxLink:

```
public string GlobalasaxLink(string SQL,string link,string field,string url)
{
    string result= "";
    SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection(connect());
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            if (dr[field].ToString() == link)
            {
                result= url+".aspx?ID=" + dr["ID"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    dr.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    return result;
}
```

content.aspx.cs:

```
string id = Request.QueryString["ID"];
            var content= from item in data.Tbl_Contents
                 where item.ID == Int32.Parse(id)
                 select item;
    foreach (var item in content)
    {
        lblContent.Text = item.content.ToString();
    }
```

and I give a link from any page like this;

```
 <a title="Read More" href="<%#Eval("url")%>"></a>
```

this is our seo tactic... We must continue with this tactic. Now the quesiton is coming again..

How can we solve the url problem(for google robot) with old web site ASP and new web site ASP.NET? You can look samples for these web sites link1 and link2..

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not changing the domain and since both old and new pages seem to have a .html extension (not asp or aspx), I'm assuming your new site will receive also the requests for the old site, which will go offline as soon as the new one goes up. 
If so, you should have your new site respond to all requests for your old urls with a 301 redirect (a permanent redirect) to the corresponding new urls. Search engines will then transfer the page ranking from the old pages to the new ones.
For instance, in the global.asax on your new site you could have something like:

```
string requestedUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
if (IsOldUrl(requestedUrl))
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", NewUrlFor(requestedUrl));
}
```

where `IsOldUrl(string oldUrl)` and `NewUrlFor(string oldUrl)` are functions you should write with the list of old urls you want redirected and the logic to map the old urls with the corresponding new ones.

On an unrelated note: looking at the snippet of your global.asax that you have posted, it looks like you're hitting the database for every request. If that's the case, I would suggest aggressive caching, if you want your site to perform decently.

Comment: @mehmetkarpuz the implementation could be a `Dictionary redirects` where you keep the old urls as key and the new urls as the corresponding value.  Then you can do: 
`if (redirects.ContainsKey(pageRequested))
{
Response.Clear();
Response.StatusCode = 301;
Response.AddHeader("Location", redirects[pageRequested]);
Response.End();
}`

Comment: ok I did this solution. But we have too much urls at old web site.. How can I do this quickly?

Comment: @mehmetkarpuz in your example url, the old url was haberlericerik-11-121-marka-tescilininde-yasanan-sorunlar.html, while the new one was marka-tescilininde-yasanan-sorunlar.html (i.e. the old one minus the initial "haberlericerik-11-121-"). Are all new urls = old urls - starting piece? And is the starting piece always of the form "word-number-number-"? If so you could automate the redirection instead of using a dictionary, by checking urls that start with a word-number-number- and redirecting them to the same url without the initial piece

Comment: redirects = new Dictionary<string, string>();
redirects.Add("haberlericerik-11-121-marka-tescilininde-yasanan-sorunlar.html", "marka-tescilininde-yasanan-sorunlar.html");
I write this this is working but we have too much urls 
like :haberlericerik-11-121-marka-tescilininde-yasanan-sorunlar.html this is one of old urls.. the numbers are ID for content.. numbers are coming from db..

Comment: @mehmetkarpuz: my question was if the old urls have all the same structure. If you see an old url can you recognize it just by looking at it? How? Do they all have the same form?

Comment: @mehmetkarpuz let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2731/discussion-between-paolo-and-mehmetkarpuz)